Setting security preferences for Edge and Chrome
I am trying to get a customer Essential Eight compliant. I'm using Datto RMM which does not seem to support config profiles and I'm not sure how else to do it.
Is there a decent guide to hacking these settings in PowerShell?
Anybody done similar?
